# Why https is disabled on publish in .NET Core 7.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0

**Explanation**

I have Visual Studio v17.9.5. When I publish an existing project or create a new one and publish it, it shows me only the http:5000 port.

It does not run neither on cloud.

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

**Question**

Why is the https port disabled on publish? How can it be enabled?

The output I get when I run the app, after publish:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
  Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
```

**Launchsettings.json**

```
     {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:6247",
      "sslPort": 44352
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5140",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7135;http://localhost:5140",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On debug i get the following:

[image]

On publish i get this :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu